# Well-asked question, but wrong title after resolution

Tags: discussion, questions

This happens all the time: **[EDIT: the question was removed by the author, but I still want to ask. Its title was "How to convert image(s) to base64 encode in PHP?", and it was well formatted. The OP was concerned about a "No such file or directory" error, which turned out to be due to an error in the path of a file]**.
I think the question is well asked. Of course, the error is due to a very simple and common mistake, and the OP could have searched more thoroughly about `No such file or directory` errors in PHP, but the format is not to throw away in my opinion.

The problem is, after the question has been solved, it is obvious that the solution is trivial, and furthermore the whole question has *nothing* to do with Base64 encoding in PHP.

**What approach should I follow here?**

1) Point out these facts to the OP and suggest he removes the question (I would do this if I was the OP)

2) Downvote / flag the question (doesn't seem quite right to me)

3) Upvote the question for clarity or leave it as it is (still, I have doubts)

4) Suggest an edit for the title (could be the best option? What would you suggest?)

I honestly can't decide. If the question is kept, people searching for Base64 encoding in PHP might land on that page and waste time reading stuff that has nothing to do with it, but at the same time the question had its validity in the beginning.

If you're not happy with my example because the OP didn't show that much of a search effort, please consider that other cases exist in which the OP can't come up with a solution even after searching, but the answer is nevertheless trivial and the title **very** misleading.

Comment: Well... that was removed while I was posting here. Please let me edit before downvoting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the title of the question conflicts with the body of what that question is asking, then by all means edit the question so that it's title reflects what it's actually asking.

If you feel that a question doesn't demonstrate sufficient research effort, or that it's not a useful question for others, then that is the textbook definition of the criteria for downvoting a question.  If you want to also post a comment explaining these problems, you're more than welcome to.

I don't see why you'd upvote a question that you think isn't helpful.

You should not be flagging the question for being poorly researched or not helpful; the appropriate way to provide that feedback is through voting.  You shouldn't be flagging a question for having a misleading title; just edit it yourself, or comment if you notice a problem but need help coming up with a better title.

Comment: That seems reasonable. So in my example I could have changed the title to "'No such file or directory' error in PHP". That way even though the OP focused mostly on what he was doing about Base64, the question will correctly correlate problem and solution.

Comment: Although, if the problem was caused by a typo or simple mistake, should we not close it as "a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographic error"?